# Creating C/C++ source file in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I am running Eclipse Mars.1 and a recent (latest?) Eclipse CDT on Fedora 23. I have a Java project and want to use C/C++ for media support. However, I can't get the IDE to create the first C file (or the second for that matter). I have created a new source folder under the Java src folder and verified that it has been created in the file system. When I R-click on that new folder and ultimately selected 'create C/C++ source file', I am presented with a 'New Source File' dialog with 2 edit fields. One is titled 'Source folder' and the other 'Source file'. No matter what I do in the 'Source folder' edit field, a status message displays that the folder doesn't exist. When I enter a file name the status field states that I haven't specified a directory. When I use the browse button to try to select a directory, nothing is displayed except a status message that says that there aren't any entries. I have enabled the C/C++ perspective, but that didn't make any difference.

I originally posted this message on the Eclipse CDT forum but didn't get an answer. I have also posted it on the Eclipse newcomers forum.

Any help or insight to resolve this difficulty would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have the C/C++ components of Eclipse installed? Why would you create a C file under the java folder?

Comment: Create a new C/C++ project, and place the new file in there. Java and C are like oil and water, they don't mix.

Answer (score 0):

Java and C do mix well through the JNI. I will implement my backend media in GStreamer, so I don't really have any option. I want it to be portable to Windows, Linux and Android (iOS later). I know that the UI will be different on Android.

I did find the answer here -> http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fcdt_t_new_cpp.htm

I had searched for the answer earlier but never found it. I think that the key was to highlight the actual Java project (not the destination directory) in the project explorer pane, then R-click/new/file. I was able to select my folder that I had created before for the C files under the project and did successfully create and have now edited a C file.